# upload and download files by user in opencms 9

Tags: file, download, upload, content-management-system, opencms

I am trying to create upload and download the files option by user from front-end created in OPENCMS 9. Could you please suggest/help me to get the solution as how to approach or any predefined modules available for the same.
I have already serached for the same and got some module "**Synyx NetbeansOpenCmsUpload Module**" but couldn't able to download this. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the jLAN Function of OpenCms:

http://documentation.opencms.org/opencms-documentation/more-opencms-features/mounting-the-vfs/network-share-access/index.html